# I want to stop a function on button click

Tags: java, android

I am using two buttons...1 is slow and other is slower...when i click on one of the either button it is working fine...now when i click on the other button, functions of previous is running simultaneously...I want methods of the one(which is already running) to stop on clicking the second one...

```
slow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setVisibilityslow1();
        }
    });

slower.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setVisibilityslower1();

        }
    });

}

private void setVisibilityslow1() {

    tv1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setVisibilityslow2();
        }
    }, 500);
}

private void setVisibilityslow2() {

    tv1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setVisibilityslow1();
        }
    }, 500);
}

private void setVisibilityslower1() {

    tv1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setVisibilityslower2();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

private void setVisibilityslower2() {

    tv1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setVisibilityslower1();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you want to avoid shutting a thread down.  There are time when it is desired and necessary.

Rather than use an anonymous class you could

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
private volatile boolean shutdown;
public void run() {
    while (!shutdown) {
        ...
    }
}
public void shutdown() {
    shutdown = true;
   }
}
```

And then run shutdown on it.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is not enough to decide but I guess what you are looking for is [Handler.removeCallbacks()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable))

Answer (score 0):

here you can achieve what you want use this code below

first initialize this out side your **onCreate**

```
private Handler visiablityHandler;
private Runnable mySlowRunnable;
```

and then replace yours with this

```
        visiablityHandler =  new Handler();

        slow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setVisibilityslowAndSlower(500);
            }
        });

        slower.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setVisibilityslowAndSlower(1000);
            }
        });
}
    private void setVisibilityslowAndSlower(final int delayMillis) {
        if(mySlowRunnable != null)
            visiablityHandler.removeCallbacks(mySlowRunnable);

        mySlowRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //here you can put what you want to do with your tv1
                visiablityHandler.postDelayed(this , delayMillis);
            }
        };
        visiablityHandler.post(mySlowRunnable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if(mySlowRunnable != null)
            visiablityHandler.removeCallbacks(mySlowRunnable);
   }
```

**hope this helps you , let me know if it does not help**

Comment: I want first button to finish its process on clicking the second button...as i have called a function inside another function and they are running for infinite time...so my motive is to stop the functionality of one button on clicking the other...

Comment: It will be more clear to me if u can just help me that where should I add your code in my given code...thank u...

Comment: aha .. ok i miss understade , i will update my answer now

Comment: Thank u for the help..but i am not able to understand that where should I call all the methods in your code that i have used in my code...ie setVisibilityslow2(),setVisibilityslow1(),setVisibilityslower2()setVisibilityslower1()

Comment: replace my code with yours .. it should work as you want .. if you click slow button its process runs and when click on slower he will stop slow button process and run slower process (and vice versa)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line of code to stop your thread:

```
tv1.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); // where tv1 is your Handler
```

If that doesn't work for you then you can stop the specific thread, like if you are running the thread like this:

```
Handler handler=  new Handler()
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
// do something
}
};
handler.postDelayed(myRunnable);
```

Then you can stop it like this:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
```

Comment: As i am beginner i am facing this issue...It will be more clear to me if u can just help me that where should I add your code in my given code...thank u..

Comment: Tell me one thing, what is "tv1"? Is this a handler or a textview?

Comment: I am getting confused with your code, Just tell me one last thing. What do you actually want to do. Like when slow button is clicked you want to hide your hide your textview with animation or something else. Because the code you are using will generate an ongoing loop. It won't stop.Your one method is calling the other one and other one is calling the first one.

Comment: Just elaborate a little bit what do you actually want to do?